# How to disable rollback for stackset in cloudformation

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

I know that we can disable rollback for stack failure for normal cloudformation stack. Is there anyway we can setup that for the stackset created by the cloudforamtion. Tried with failure tolerance, however the failed stack getting rollbacked, any advice ?